# After installing reactify, cmd giving an error that browserify is not an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, browserify, reactify

I am trying for a jsx transformation. I've installed react-tool, react and reactify. I think reactify is a plugin for browserify and we don't need to install browserify if we have reactify. But when running the command `browserify -t reactify public/js/flux/index.js > public/js/build/index.js` , I'm getting an error of `"browserify is not an internal or external command."`

What would be the solution for this?

Comment: do you have browserify installed globally?

Comment: No. I didn't install it. Somewhere I read that reactify is enough for jsx transformation and for require() module. But After installing browserify everything is going nicely. Thank you.

Comment: Nah, still need browserify mate, and glad you figured it out!